# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.parse

Tags: csv, apache-spark, sbt

I get this error when running the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.parse
```

This is my SBT assembly file:

```
name := "mytest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

organization := "org.test"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

val mahoutVersion = "0.12.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  // Mahout's Spark libs
  "org.apache.mahout" %% "mahout-math-scala" % mahoutVersion,
  "org.apache.mahout" %% "mahout-spark" % mahoutVersion
    exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-core_2.10"),
  "org.apache.mahout"  % "mahout-math" % mahoutVersion,
  "org.apache.mahout"  % "mahout-hdfs" % mahoutVersion
    exclude("com.thoughtworks.xstream", "xstream")
    exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-client"),
  // other external libs
  "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.3.2",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.16.0"
    exclude("org.apache.commons", "commons-csv"),
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.3.0",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark_2.10" % "2.3.0"
    exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-catalyst_2.10")
    exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-sql_2.10"))

resolvers += "typesafe repo" at " http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("org", "joda", "time", "base", "BaseDateTime.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "csv", "CSVParser.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "csv", "CSVPrinter.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", "csv", "ExtendedBufferedReader.class") => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "package-info.class" =>
    MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

I also tested `"com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0"`  and `"com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.4.0"`, but the same error appears all the time. I know that it has something to do with dependencies. Do I need to add any other library?

Comment: You're almost certainly pulling in an incompatible version of `commons-csv` as a transitive dependency. I would suggest removing all non-direct dependencies from your declarations (those things you aren't referencing directly from your code), and also removing the `exclude` lines.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problematic class path.

I would avoid using "assemblyMergeStrategy" to fix the classpath like this. It works ok if you have configuration file conflicts, like log4j, but if you have this kind of a mess, it's really not the right tool for the job.

**Suggested solution:**
Use `exclude("org.apache.commons", "commons-csv")` in all the dependencies that use `commons-csv`. Leave out only the one that you actually need (in this case the one from spark).

I would overall try to fix the classpath with exclusion rules without having to use "assemblyMergeStrategy".

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post a sample `libraryDependencies` showing what you mean by `leave out only the one that you actually need (in this case the one from spark)`?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity :

If you have a dependency on apache-solr you probably have a conflict with the dependency `solr-commons-csv.jar` which embeds a class with the same name (`org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser`)